# Using formulas in description of a TextBox in SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, list

Is it possible that we can make use of formulas in description textbox of a field?

I want to append another field value in the desciption. e.g.

[image]

Here, comments is field and in its description I'm trying to reference another field `FormURL`. All I'm getting right now is same string.

If this is not possible then what could be the work around to this?

Comment: This is not possible by using description field. Does FormURL field present in the same list? Does it has value prepoulated or user will enter the value in NewForm?

Comment: Any workaround then?

Comment: Is the FormURL field value is prepopulated?

Comment: It is populated when a new item is created using Workflow

Comment: So only in EditForm you need the functionality. Right?

Comment: Yeah..Only EditForm

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the below JaveScript in the EditFrom.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
var fldObj = $("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('Comments')").parent().parent().parent();
var text=$("td.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader nobr:contains('FormURL')").parent().parent().parent().find('input').val();
fldObj.find('input').parent().parent().append('<span class="ms-metadata">'+text+'</span>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tip: You can save on all those ``parent()`` statements (and make it failsave) with the ``GetAncestor()`` function you get for free from SharePoints ``core.js``